# Nexmo/Vonage : Client error: `GET https://api.nexmo.com/beta/users` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized`

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, vonage

I try to get list users from vonage API with laravel http client but get code 401. this the response:

```
{"description":"You did not provide a valid token. Please provide a valid token.","code":"system:error:invalid-token"}
```

this my source code:

```
$keypair = new \Vonage\Client\Credentials\Keypair(file_get_contents(storage_path('private.key')), $client->properties['application_id']);
    $basicClient = new \Vonage\Client($keypair);

    $claims = [
      'acl' => [
        'paths' => [
          '/*/users/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/conversations/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/sessions/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/devices/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/image/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/media/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/applications/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/push/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/knocking/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/legs/**' => (object) [],
        ]
      ]
    ];

    $jwt = $basicClient->generateJwt($claims);
    $response = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
    $http = Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/json'])->withToken((string) $jwt)->get('https://api.nexmo.com/beta/users');
    dd($http->body());
```

seem like i mess up with jwt but i don't know where did i wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The token generation itself looks fine, but you can double-check against https://jwt.io/ to see if the token looks OK (correct app ID, claims, etc). This usually is a malformed JWT, a time mismatch (your server/computer is too far ahead or behind), wrong key used, or wrong app ID. You can also drop the `$response` line, as you are just creating a Guzzle client without doing anything with it and the Laravel HTTP client will use it automatically.

Comment: @dragonmantank i edited my question provided jwt result, but it looks like fine